# Count occurrences of character in a string and Group By with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to count occurrences and to add group by after, but I have an error

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column ‘bdd.my_table.text' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

My table :

```
id | book | chapter | text
 1 |   1  |    1    | 'hello hello world'
 2 |   1  |    2    | 'hello hello hello hello'
 3 |   1  |    3    | 'world'
 4 |   1  |    4    | 'hello test'
```

I execute my request :

```
SELECT 
    book,
    chapter,
    text,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(text)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( text, "hello", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("hello")        
    ) AS count    
FROM my_table
WHERE book=43
GROUP BY chapter
```

I would like this result :

```
book | chapter | count
----------------------
  43  |    1    |   2
  43  |    2    |   4
  43  |    3    |   0
  43  |    4    |   1
```

I tried to add this before the request to remove 'only_full_group_by', but I have the same problem

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `group by`, you should tell us what you are expecting. If you just want to solve this issue, remove `only_full_group_by` attribute in sql_mode.

Comment: I updated my post with the resut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, even I still don't know what you exactly want to do till now, but try it.

```
SELECT
    book,
    chapter,
    group_concat(text) as text,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(group_concat(text))
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( group_concat(text), "hello", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("hello")        
    ) AS `count`
FROM my_table
GROUP BY chapter, book
```

Comment: Thx ! The results arn't correct, for example the result is 5 and with this request I have only the result 2

Comment: @Forward I didn't get why its not working when we add column `text` in group by and use it in Select (or) Length/Replace function? Why we need to use group_concat which will do concat operation if multiple text found right?

Comment: I think you should want to count all `hello`s for each chapter. If it is, of course, you do not need to add `text` in `group by`. See [***demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11beb/2) in sqlfiddle.

Comment: Thx @Forward, I added SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; to extend the concat

Comment: @Forward, How can I use your solution without SET SESSION or SET all the time ?

Comment: @JérémieChazelle Like `group_concat_max_len ` and `only_full_group_by `, they are mysql system variables, you can set them in global not in current session.

Comment: Thx @Forward SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

Answer (score 0):

All column in the `SELECT` list should present in `GROUP BY` clause. So please add all `SELECT` list columns in `GROUP BY` clause **(or)** remove from  `SELECT` list which is not in `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT 
    book,
    chapter,   
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(text)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( text, "hello", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("hello")        
    ) AS count    
FROM my_table
WHERE book=43
GROUP BY book, chapter, text
```

Comment: Thx for your comment but when I add GROUP BY book, chapter, text, I have the same result with not GROUP BY

Comment: As per your error message, `text` field is not present in GROUP BY clause and you tried to do some aggregate operation causes the issue. I hope the above query may solve your issue.

Comment: With your post, I have the same message : Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bdd.my_table.text' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by, the chapters are not group by...

Comment: The chapters arn't GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT book, chapter,
       SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 'hello', 'hellox')) - LENGTH(text)) as cnt
FROM my_table
WHERE book = 43
GROUP BY book, chapter;
```

Notice that the `COUNT()` is much simpler -- no division.  This replaces `hello` with a string one character longer and then subtracts the length of the original text.

Comment: I have an error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 'hello', 'hellox')) - LENGTH(text)) as cnt